# Unable to boot to Windows Vista after reinstalling Linux in a dual boot configuration

Tags: linux, boot, windows-vista, centos, multi-boot

I had a dual boot of Vista and Arch Linux. I wanted to delete Arch and install CentOS so I formatted the following partitions of the existing installation and installed CentOS 7:

```
/
/boot
/swap
```

I haven't touched the Windows partitions. How can I boot back to Windows?

Comment: What happens when you boot? What do you mean you can't boot into windows? Please make your question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only formatted the partitions then you will need to decide if you want to install CentOS to those partitions - and manually select the partitions during the install - or delete the partitions (leaving "free space" on the disk) and let the CentOS installer guide you through the partition creation using the free space (it does the partitioning for you).

Once the install has completed it should install GRUB (GRUB2 I should think) - I'm not a CentOS user - and it should automatically identify that Windows is installed elsewhere on the disk and create the menu entry to allow chainloading the Windows Boot Manager - thus allowing you to choose which OS when you start your computer.

Either case you should be able to repair GRUB2 and it should look for the OSes installed and create entries for them. Ubuntu certainly does this...